# React Hook is called in function that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, eslint

I have this following ESLint warning :

> React Hook "useBuilderFeatureFlagContext" is called in function "Slide.RenderBuilder" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function.

and this is the following component :

```
Slide.RenderBuilder = ({ children }) => {
  const flags = useBuilderFeatureFlagContext();

  return (
    <>
      <SlideWrapper $flags={flags}>
        {children}
      </SlideWrapper>
      <ImageSetter attributeName="containerBackgroundImage" />
    </>
  );
};
```

How do I write a rule that can whitelist this specific case ?

Comment: have you tried create a function component named `RenderBuilder` then assign it to the `Slide constructor` (assuming) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can, define the component first, then add it to your object.

```
const RenderBuilder = ({ children }) => {
  const flags = useBuilderFeatureFlagContext();

  return (/**/);
};

Slide.RenderBuilder = RenderBuilder;
```

That way, the rule properly check for hooks, and you have the structure you're looking for.

Make sure to use it as a component `<Slide.RenderBuilder />` otherwise you might end up breaking rules of hooks.